# react-native 0.59 how to create a native request permission on android

Tags: android, react-native

I am new on react-native and I am using 0.59.
I need to show the request permission on location with "Allow all the time" for the background geolocation.

It is working on API 28. But, when migrating to API 29 it doesn't appear.

Based on the android docs, you need to list down the permission manually.

Currently. I have the following.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

on my custom service
/service/Geolocation.java

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void requestForLocationPermission(Promise promise) {
        String result = "";

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getReactApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
        
        
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            promise.resolve("granted");
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                },
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
            );
        }
    }
```

Im having this error

[image]

How do i extend the MainActivity on my module.
Or is there any possible way for the permissoin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast current activity to AppCompatActivity to remove the error. Therefore, replace `this` with `(AppCompatActivity) getCurrentActivity()`.

Comment: is this using androidx? Sorry, I am not fully aware with the native

Comment: looks the same with solutiion

Comment: Yes the answer above is using `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my end

```
import android.app.Activity;

...

final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
            
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    activity,
    new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    },
    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
);
```